# C++ MFC Multithreading: why a modal dialog blocks everything on all threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, user-interface, mfc

I have a bit strange problem in my (unfortunately) MFC code:

To manage special functions in my SplashScreen window I've created a CWinThread derived runtime_class to create an UI thread which manage a CWnd object to show the splashscreen and some info, using the OnTimer event.

What happens is that the moment a Modal dialog appears, called by the mainthread, the splashscreen OnTimer is no more called. If I reach to close the modal dialog, then the message pump of the thread unfreeze and the onTimer function return to work fine.

I haven't found **any** information on how to register the wndclass for the CWnd to be independent from the main thread, so my fear is that I do something wrong registering the class, this is the code of the WNDCLASSEX structure

```
   WNDCLASSEX wcx{ 0 };

   wcx.cbSize = sizeof( wcx );
   wcx.lpfnWndProc = AfxWndProc;
   wcx.style = CS_DBLCLKS | CS_SAVEBITS /* | CS_DROPSHADOW*/;
   wcx.cbClsExtra = 0;
   wcx.cbWndExtra = 0;
   wcx.hInstance = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
   wcx.hIcon = nullptr;
   wcx.hCursor = LoadCursor( nullptr, IDC_ARROW );
   wcx.hbrBackground = ::GetSysColorBrush( COLOR_WINDOW );
   wcx.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
   wcx.lpszClassName = L"SplashScreenExClass";
   wcx.hIconSm = nullptr;

   ATOM classAtom = RegisterClassEx( &wcx );
```

I think that these two AfxBlahBlah function calls aren't so right, but I can't find neither in MSDN documentation nor in examples what I have to do.
The thread class is in a static library linked in the main executable, so no DLL involved.

Can you please help me?

I tried to change the registering method using AfxRegisterClass() function and changing AfxWndProc with ::DefWindowProc.
I've debugged the event loop to check if they comes from the mainthread or the secondary thread, and verified they come from the secondary thread

this is a sample of how is managed the thread and the CWnd:

```
CSplashScreenMgr::CSplashScreenMgr() noexcept
{
   m_Thread = reinterpret_cast<CSplashScreenThread*>( AfxBeginThread( RUNTIME_CLASS( CSplashScreenThread ) ) );
   if ( m_Thread )
      m_Thread->m_bAutoDelete = false;
   Sleep( 1000 );
}
...

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
void
CSplashScreenMgr::Show()
{
   if ( m_Thread )
      m_Thread->PostThreadMessage( CS_SHOW, 0, 0 );
}
...
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE( CSplashScreenThread, CWinThread )
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
BOOL
CSplashScreenThread::InitInstance()
{
   m_pSplash = new CSplashScreen();
   m_pMainWnd = m_pSplash;

   return TRUE;
}
...
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP( CSplashScreenThread, CWinThread )
ON_THREAD_MESSAGE( CS_SHOW, OnShow )
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void
CSplashScreenThread::OnShow( WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
   if ( !m_pSplash )
      return;
   //... info setted on m_pSplash
   m_pSplash->Show();
}

// CSplashScreen
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC( CSplashScreen, CWnd )

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP( CSplashScreen, CWnd )
ON_WM_TIMER()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CSplashScreen::CSplashScreen()
{
   WNDCLASSEX wcx{ 0 };

   wcx.cbSize = sizeof( wcx );
   wcx.lpfnWndProc = AfxWndProc;
   wcx.style = CS_DBLCLKS | CS_SAVEBITS;
   wcx.cbClsExtra = 0;
   wcx.cbWndExtra = 0;
   wcx.hInstance = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
   wcx.hIcon = nullptr;
   wcx.hCursor = LoadCursor( nullptr, IDC_ARROW );
   wcx.hbrBackground = ::GetSysColorBrush( COLOR_WINDOW );
   wcx.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
   wcx.lpszClassName = L"SplashScreenExClass";
   wcx.hIconSm = nullptr;

   ATOM classAtom = RegisterClassEx( &wcx );
   // some checks on classAtom return...
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void
CSplashScreen::Show( void )
{
   if ( !IsWindow( this->m_hWnd ) ) {
      if ( !CreateEx( WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_LAYERED, L"SplashScreenExClass", nullptr, WS_POPUP, m_Splash.nXPos, m_Splash.nYPos, m_Splash.nWidth, m_Splash.nHeight, m_pWndParent ? m_pWndParent->GetSafeHwnd() : nullptr, nullptr ) ) {
         OutputDebugString( L"Unable to create SplashScreenExClass window\n" );
         return;
      }
   }
   SetWindowPos( &wndTopMost, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOACTIVATE );

   if ( m_dwTimeout != 0 )
      SetTimer( TIMER_TIMEOUT, m_dwTimeout, nullptr );
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void
CSplashScreen::OnTimer( UINT_PTR unIDEvent )
{
   switch ( unIDEvent ) {
//...
      case TIMER_TIMEOUT:
         KillTimer( TIMER_TIMEOUT );
         PostQuitMessage( 0 );
         break;
   }

   CWnd::OnTimer( unIDEvent );
}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us. Especially how you create the thread.

Comment: Window class registration is not at all concerned with threads. A window is owned by the thread that called `CreateWindowExW`, regardless of where its class was registered. Changing the class registration code isn't going to fix anything. The real fix would be to not create a window hierarchy across threads (see [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)). I'm guessing here, since we cannot see your code.

Comment: Sorry @Someprogrammerdude , I've added an extract of my code starting from the class which create the thread to the CWnd class, I've omitted it 'cause I was thinking it will be "too much" :D

Comment: Does the code eventually call [`CWinThread::Run()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinthread-class#run)? If you don't then messages aren't getting dispatched (unless you get lucky with the system calling `AttachThreadInput` behind your back).

Comment: @IInspectable within the AfxBeginThread it's called the Run. The Splashscreen works fine, all the messages are received until I have a modal dialog called. The thread pump message it's working, I've checked that

Comment: Is the modal dialog owned by the same thread? Also note that [thread messages are eaten by modal loops](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050426-18/?p=35783).

Comment: @IInspectable no, the modal dialog is called by the mainthread

Comment: A relatively easy test would be to make a similar Win32 (non-MFC) application, ie start a new UI thread (for the splash window), but display a modal dialog instead of a main (WS_OVERLAPPED) window. The VS project templates include such skeleton projects. The amount of work required is not insignificant but not large either. This will tell you if the "problem" (ie displaying a modal dialog in the main thread blocks message processing in other UI threads) is a Windows feature or a MFC library oversight. In the former case a radically different solution is required. You can also upload a MRE.

Comment: A modal dialog affects the thread that owns it alone. Unless the owner of that modal dialog is owned by a different thread. Which is the kind of issue you ***never*** want to find yourself in (see the link from my first comment).